# Install old vesrion of chrome alongside latest chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, installation

I want to test some websites in older versions of Chrome (from the year 2018-2019). At the same time, I want to be able to use the latest version Google chrome for regular use (browsing, checking emails, etc).

I believe that:

- You cannot have two Chrome browsers installed on same machine or for same user
- Chrome will try to autoupdate itself

What possible solution do i have to be able to use one version of Chrome for testing and current versin of Chrome for office work, **both at the same time**. We're using Windows and only one Windows user will need the extra chrome browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a portable version of Chrome. The latest version can be found here https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable

If you want an older version, however, there is an achieve here of them https://google-chrome-portable.en.uptodown.com/windows/versions

Comment: Instead of "free software download" websites, you can download any version of "Chromium" from google servers. [This website](https://vikyd.github.io/download-chromium-history-version/) maintains a list of the URLs. The downloads do not contain any installer. Just extract and run. Browsing data is usually stored in user's home directory.